# Adding a column in Pandas based on multiple conditions on another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to add a `Year` column to my DataFrame based on the value that already exists within the `Rk` column. I've tried using the code below, however it automatically sets all values to `0`.

```
df['Year'] = np.where(df['Rk'] <= 540, '2017/2018', 0)
df['Year'] = np.where((df['Rk'] >= 541) & (df['Rk'] <= 1135), '2016/2017', 0)
df['Year'] = np.where((df['Rk'] >= 1136) & (df['Rk'] <= 1713), '2016/2017', 0)
```

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52721283/edit) to include example data demonstrating your problem?

Comment: I am removing `matplotlib` tag as neither your question nor your code in its present form has anything to do with it. The same goes for `seaborn`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with specify bins:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Rk': [10, 540,541,1135,1136,1713,1714,2000],

})

labs = ['2017/2018','2016/2017','2015/2016', '0']
df['Year'] = pd.cut(df['Rk'], bins=[-np.inf,540, 1135, 1713, np.inf], labels=labs)
print (df)
     Rk       Year
0    10  2017/2018
1   540  2017/2018
2   541  2016/2017
3  1135  2016/2017
4  1136  2015/2016
5  1713  2015/2016
6  1714          0
7  2000          0
```